# asp.net response.redirect hitting url, but not changing browser page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, response.redirect

I have an aspx page (webforms) that is called from a jQuery Post method (which works fine), however the Response.Redirect method from the code behind does not reload the browser with the redirected URL. It does actually hit the URL, however. 
I'm pretty sure this has something to do with the page being called from jQuery, but not sure why this behavior is happening.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        //lid = Validation.StripToGUID(ObjToGUID(Request.QueryString("lid")))
        lid = Validation.StripToGUID(ObjToGUID(Request.Form["lid"]));
        string sid = null;
        if (lid.Length == 36)
        {
            //retrieve the link (and product data) from the database
            LiveItem_Data.DBConnStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
            LiveItem o = new LiveItem();
            o = LiveItem_Data.GetLive_ItemFromLID(lid);


            if (HTTPStuff.RemoteFileExists(o.product_link))
            {
                Response.Redirect(o.product_link, true);
            }
            else
            {
                //generate an error                 
            }


        }

    }
}
```

I stepped through the code and the product_link is working (manually cutting and pasting into a browser), and the remote page is being called (I'm testing the link with another site that has logging).
The browser however does not open (tried FF, IE, Opera, Chrome) the new URL.

The jQuery post:

```
$('.popInfoHG').click(function () {
    var ListID = $(this).parent().find('[id*=hidlid]').val();
    $.post("redir.aspx", { lid: ListID });
});
```

I verified that HTTPredirect feature is turned on in IIS Express (from Visual Studio 2012). Stumped!

Comment: Why did you keep `true` for `Response.Redirect(o.product_link, true);`

Comment: To end the response, but false does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

I think from the jquery function, it will not redirect the page from server you will have to do this on client side itself i.e in the success part of the click function

```
$('.popInfoHG').click(function () {
    var ListID = $(this).parent().find('[id*=hidlid]').val();
    $.post("redir.aspx", { lid: ListID }).success(function() {

//write the redirection code here

});
});
```

Comment: Good point. Maybe I should put the RemoteFileExists method inside a webservice that takes a lid (listing id) as the param (it's extremely lightweight/low latency way of determining a link is valid w/o loading it), the return the url and redirect from jQuery. It will probably run faster - a full postback is not really necessary in this case.

Comment: The only problem with not having a full postback (posting to a redirect page) is that I run into the dreaded pop-up blocker problem - which will scare people away (unfortunately, there is no way to bypass window.open causing popup blockers to engage). 
I think I just need to use a hyperlink to my redir page with a querystring (like http://mysite/redir.aspx?lid=xxxx) in the href with the target as _blank, then use response.redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're using post right.  Post is for making a hidden service call and does not affect the browser window.

If you just want to redirect the browser window, and redir.aspx will accept either GET or POST, you can use window.location.href:

```
$('.popInfoHG').click(function () {
    var ListID = $(this).parent().find('[id*=hidlid]').val();
    window.location.href = "redir.aspx?lid=" + ListID;
});
```

If redir.aspx does not accept GET, I suggest you create a hidden form on your page (with an lid hidden input element) and post it programmatically.

Comment: Agreed. I had actually wanted to open a new window leaving the old one open, not just a redirect of the original page. I'm just using standard link to the redir.aspx page, then, from server side, it does a response.redirect to the new url (after recording the click & other info on the server side for tracking demographics). This way, a message will not show up in the visitor's browser asking to allow a popup (which is desired).